# How to copy updated files in batches of limited size?

Tags: macos, rsync, bandwidth

I'm on a Mac, and I want to copy, incrementally, files that have changed, to a new location. An rsync kind of arrangement. But, because of what happens to them next, I want to limit how many GB get copied in each run of the job.

If, say, I run it each night from a cron job, the amount of data has some kind of constraint, though it doesn't need to be very precise.

Ideally, it would be something like "Copy any new files in directory tree A to directory tree B, but stop after the first file that takes you over 2GB copied in this run".  (I *do* want all files to be copied eventually, so a single large one shouldn't kill it.)

I could obviously write some code to do this, but wondered if there were any apps, obscure rsync options, ingenious uses of tar or cpio, that would save me the trouble...

(For the curious, I'm copying to my FileTransporter, which then syncs to one in my brother's house, but he has a slower connection than me and I don't want any given change to take more than a couple of hours each night.)

Comment: This may sound a bit brute, but how about if you just have another cronjob running after N hours (e.g.) which kills the previously started rsync to your FileTransporter in case it's still running? That'd sound like easiest way of doing things and the rsync itself will make sure anything left unfinished will be corrected on the next run (or later).

Comment: Mmm.  You're right, that would probably work, if I can get over the inelegance of it!  But it would also mean partial files might be handed on to the next stage, which could be nasty.  (unless rsync can be sent a signal that says it should stop after next file...)